# Why does "Mix.env()" become nil on production when being called in a layout?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I added this to my base layout file:

```
<%= if Mix.env() in [:prod] do %>
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?........................
    </script>
<% end %>
```

and it crashes on production because of  supposedely being "Mix.env()" nil.

**But the same code works on my local machine in the development environment.**

How to fix it?

**update1**

However, why does this work on **both development and production**?

```
  # /lib/my_module1.ex
  defmodule MyAppWeb.MyModule1 do
    use Plug.Builder

    unless Mix.env() in [:prod] do
      # some stuff here
      # all works, no exception thrown
```

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: Why do you expect to have `mix` in production available in the first place? @Dogbert I might guess the error message: it’s something like “(UndefinedFunctionError) function Mix.env/0 is undefined (module Mix is not available)”

Comment: @mudasobwa why wouldn't I?

Comment: Because Elixir in `dev` env implicitly loads several additional applications that are not included in production distribution. `Mix` is one of them, because it is _a build tool_ in the first place.

Comment: @mudasobwa what's your solution to my issue then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Mix` is not included into OTP releases by default. Elixir does implicitly load several applications while running via `mix`, including but not limited to `:mix`, `:runtime_tools`, `:observer`.

<sup>I am struggled to find a reference to prove that right now, if anybody knows the reference, please share in comments I’ll update the answer.</sup>

While one might explicitly include `:mix` into releases by adding it to the list of `:included_applications` in the `MyApp.Mixfile` [**don’t do that! that’s plain wrong**], the proper solution would be to rely on environment variables, controlled by the project owner. That said, set an environment variable on your production hosts, in some `.rc` file:

```
export MYAPP_PROD=true
```

or in your `systemctl`/`upstart` script, or explicitly while running the release:

```
MYAPP_PROD=true bin/my_app foreground
```

And check it with [`System.get_env/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/System.html#get_env/1):

```
<%= if System.get_env("MYAPP_PROD") do %>
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?...
    </script>
<% end %>
```

Comment: If you have another question, ask another question. Also, “why this code is not working” is explicitly prohibited on SO question. Also, please clarify, what do mean  when you write “production”. Release? Deployed release? Just locally set environment?

Comment: BTW, `unless Mix.env() in [:prod]` is plain wrong as well. One should not rely on environment that is set on compilation host. Also, please note, that your conditional is _not a conditional_ in fact, the code is either included in release or nor, based on compilation-time settings. You surely need to understand the difference between compilation time and runtime.

Comment: i don't know what I mean; whatever is deployed to my server via edeliver. what kind of release is that?

Comment: Well, it’s a deployed release. Where do you build it then? The same server? If yes, this server has a `mix` installed.

Comment: `Also, please note, that your conditional is not a conditional in fact, the code is either included in release or nor,` ----> yes, that's what I need. How will this make a difference: being a true conditional or "either included or not"?

Comment: Whenever you decide to change this parameter, you need to deploy. Also, you have to compile different releases for staging and for production.

Comment: ok. can I put "prod: true" to my prod. config file  and use it instead of an env. variable you showed? any downsides to a config file?

Comment: Config files are _compilation-time_ beasts as well. Values are loaded from configs during compilation stage. If you are fine with hard-coded settings, you might use configs. If you want a runtime-setting, environment is a way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Mix does not have to exist in a runtime. It is a build tool, used in compilation phase. You may replace `Mix.env()` with the function like:

```
@env Mix.env()
def env, do: @env
```

So it will determine which environment it is during the compile time.

Comment: `Mix does not have to exist in a runtime.` --> how does it manage to exist on my local machine in the dev mode, in the same layout file?

Comment: This is where you compile it, on the local machine. The you send compiled files to production. Without Mix, as it is not needed there.

Comment: suppose I go with your solution. Still, how can I call that `env` from my `layout/app.html`?

Comment: This is very error-prone. For instance, staging releases might be compiled with `MIX_ENV` set to `prod` and your staging instances all of a sudden will report to GA. For the proper solution, check my answer. After all, compilation host environment should not be responsible for setting an environment in production.